# ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Butterknife Gradle plugin version 9.0.0-rc2 and higher

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am update android studio to 3.3, in my project I get this error:

```
ERROR: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Butterknife Gradle plugin version 9.0.0-rc2 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'MyProject' -> com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1
Affected Modules: app
```

and I am ready update Butterknife to 9.0.0-rc2

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
```

Answer (score 9):

Are you using androidx in your app/library?
If so, I would bump the butterknife version to the stable `10.0.0` version, otherwise update to the stable `9.0.0` one.

**Without androidx:**

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0'
```

**With androidx:**

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```

You can find more about it in the change log [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Answer (score 4):

You need to update the Butter Knife plugin inside your **project** `build.gradle` to something like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem here. The way to fix this is to update in the build.grandle(Project) with this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'
}
```

and in the build.grandle(App) with this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0-rc2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0-rc2'
}
```

Keep in mind that in this version the  @InjectView is replace with @BindView.